# Laravel 5.5 eloquent request in blade and many sql queries

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need output user payments history. With payment method detail. Like card or paypall data for each payment

```
<table border="1">
        <tr>
        <th>
        </th>
        <th>
            summ
        </th>
        <th>
            date
        </th>
        <th>
            payment method
        </th>
        <th>
            subscription
        </th>
        <th></th>
        </tr>
    @foreach($user -> payments()->get() as $payment)
        <tr>
            <td>
            {{$payment->type}}
            </td>
            <td>
            {{$payment->amount}}$
            </td>
            <td>
            {{$payment->created_at}}
            </td>
            <td>
                   @if($payment -> payment_method()->first()->type == PaymentMethod::PAYPAL_ACCOUNT)
                        <div><strong>Paypal: </strong> {{ $payment -> payment_method() -> first() -> paypal_email }}</div>
                    @else
                        <div><strong>Card: </strong>{{ $payment -> payment_method() -> first() -> card_brand }} **** **** **** {{ $payment -> payment_method() -> first() -> card_last_four }}</div>
                    @endif
            </td>
            <td>
                <div><strong>plan:</strong> {{ $payment->subscription->plan->name }}</div>
                <div><strong>period:</strong> {{ $payment->period_start->format('d.m.Y')}} - {{ $payment->period_end->format('d.m.Y') }}</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                @if (!empty($payment -> void_at))
                    <div>void {{ $payment -> void_at }}</div>
                @elseif (!empty($payment->refund_at))
                    <div>refunded {{ $payment->refund_at }} </div>
                @elseif(!empty($payment->refunded_transaction_id ))
                     <div>refund</div>
                @endif
            </td>  
        </tr> 
    @endforeach
</table>
```

This code generates many sql request's in each cycle iteration:

```
select * from `payment_method` where `payment_method`.`id` = '3' and `payment_method`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1

select * from `payment_method` where `payment_method`.`id` = '3' and `payment_method`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1
```

My models:

User class. With realation to payment one to many

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

    public function payments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Payment::class, $this->getForeignKey())->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }

}
```

Payment class with relation to payment method one to one

```
class Payment extends Model
{

    public function payment_method()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(PaymentMethod::class, 'payment_method_id', 'id');
    }
```

How change my code for avoid this

Comment: What you want exactly your question is not pointing any of the issue you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
$user = User::with("payments")->find($user_id);
```

and use `foreach`

```
@foreach($user->payments as $payment)
    {{$payment->type}}
@endforeach
```

Off course, you can change this piece of code as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

i do Eeager loading two relation

```
class User
....
public function paymentWithMethod()
{
    return $this->payments()->with('payment_method', 'subscription.plan')->get();
}
```